# Open an Ionic image modal on button click

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and I want to create a ionic modal that should open an image on clicking a button.
Should I achieve this using modal or ionic popup? Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I achieved this using custom popup..Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I would use a modal window. In the controller (remember to include $ionicModal in the constructor arguments):

```
// Init dialog
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(
  'templates/show-image.html', {
    scope: $scope, animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then( function( modal ) {
    $scope.modalView = modal;
  }
);
// Open dialog
$scope.buttonClick = function() {
  $scope.myimage = '...';
  $scope.modalView.show();
};
```

And the modal template show-image.html:

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
    <h1 class="title">My Image</h1>
    <div class="buttons"><button class="button button-clear" ng-click="modalView.hide()"><i class="icon ion-close"></i></button></div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <img ng-src="myimage" />
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: I achieved this using custom popup..Thanks anyways @Mat